# Handlebars: Partial not found on first run

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js

I have a node script to compile a template using handlebars. Here's my template:

```
<div class="header">
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
</div>
<div class="body">
    <p>{{body}}</p>
</div>
<div class="footer">
    <div><a href="http://twitter.com/{{author.twitter}}">{{autor.name}}</a>
    </div>
    <ul>
      {{#each tags}}
        <li>{{this}}</li>
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
    {{> example_partial}}
</div>
```

The corresponding partial is

```
<div>
  <p>
    Hi, I am a partial!
  </p>
</div>
```

And the JS

```
var handlebars = require('handlebars'),
  fs = require('fs');

var data = {
  title: 'practical node.js',
  author: '@azat_co',
  tags: ['express', 'node', 'javascript']
}
data.body = process.argv[2];

fs.readFile('handlebars-example-partial.html', 'utf-8', function(error, source) {
  handlebars.registerPartial('example_partial', source);
});

fs.readFile('handlebars-example.html', 'utf-8', function(error, source){

  var template = handlebars.compile(source);
  var html = template(data);
  console.log(html)
});
```

What I can't really figure out then when I run the script via node for the first time using `node app.js`, I get the following error:

```
/Users/rahul/stencil/node_modules/handlebars/dist/cjs/handlebars/runtime.js:266
    throw new _exception2['default']('The partial ' + options.name + ' could not be found');
    ^
Error: The partial example_partial could not be found
    at Object.invokePartial (/Users/rahul/stencil/node_modules/handlebars/dist/cjs/handlebars/runtime.js:266:11)
    at Object.invokePartialWrapper [as invokePartial] (/Users/rahul/stencil/node_modules/handlebars/dist/cjs/handlebars/runtime.js:68:39)
    at Object.eval (eval at createFunctionContext (/Users/rahul/stencil/node_modules/handlebars/dist/cjs/handlebars/compiler/javascript-compiler.js:254:23), <anonymous>:16:28)
    at main (/Users/rahul/stencil/node_modules/handlebars/dist/cjs/handlebars/runtime.js:173:32)
    at ret (/Users/rahul/stencil/node_modules/handlebars/dist/cjs/handlebars/runtime.js:176:12)
    at ret (/Users/rahul/stencil/node_modules/handlebars/dist/cjs/handlebars/compiler/compiler.js:525:21)
    at /Users/rahul/stencil/examples/standalone_v1/handlebars-example.js:29:14
    at tryToString (fs.js:414:3)
    at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:401:12)
```

However, when I run the program again, it works fine and I get the expected output (without changing anything). Could someone plese explain to me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: How do you get the error to come back? I've started a small repo with your code but after seeing the error (actually occured on 2nd compile) I cannot get it back.

Comment: Hey @adam-beck, it usually comes back for me if I edit the js file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is your partial isn't actually registered by the time you get to compiling the template that uses it. This is because `fs.readFile` is an asynchronous operation.

One solution would be to use `fs.readFileSync`:

```
var partial = fs.readFileSync('handlebars-example-partial.html', 'utf-8'); 
handlebars.registerPartial('example_partial', partial);

fs.readFile('handlebars-example.html', 'utf-8', function(error, source){
  var template = handlebars.compile(source);                                                                                                                                                                                                 
  var html = template(data);                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
  console.log(html)
});
```

Or you could put it all in the callback of the registering of the partial:

```
fs.readFile('handlebars-example-partial.html', 'utf-8', function(error, partial) {
  handlebars.registerPartial('example_partial', partial);
  fs.readFile('handlebars-example.html', 'utf-8', function(error, template) {
    var compiled = handlebars.compile(template);
    var html = compiled(data);
    console.log(html);
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, now I know what was going wrong. Just a small correction in the above code (for anyone who copy-pastes it ;) )

`handlebars.registerPartial('example_partial', source);` should be
`handlebars.registerPartial('example_partial', partial);`